# Is there a way to pass a string variable to remove() in c

Tags: c, file, file-io, io

Okay, so this is the function I'm using `remove()`:

```
int fmove(const char * filepth, const char * destpth)
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen(filepth, "r+");

    FILE * fpdest;
    fpdest = fopen(destpth, "w");

    if ((fp != NULL) && (fpdest != NULL))
    {
        char fpdata[999];
        fgets(fpdata, 999, fp);
        fputs(fpdata, fpdest);

        remove(filepth);
    } else
    {
        prtmessage("ERROR", "Cannot move file!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but the `remove()` returns -1. I know that arrays return their pointers (am I telling it right?), but is there a way to pass the string in the `filepath` to `remove()`?

Comment: If `remove` returns `-1` it means there's an error. You then need to check the value of `errno`, or perhaps use `perror` to print a string with the error.

Comment: As for the problem, are you perhaps on a Windows system? Then you can't remove files which are opened by any process, not even your own. There can be no process which have the file opened, or removing it will fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C Standard

> If the file is open, the behavior of the remove function is
> implementation-defined.

You need to close the file before calling `remove()`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I never thought of that.